# Multiple HTML Table to Excel conversion

Tags: php, html, excel

I want to convert HTML table to worksheets and multiple tables on same page should be converted into a workbook.

```
var htmltable= document.getElementById('table');
var html = htmltable.outerHTML;
window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(html));'
```

I have already tried this code to convert html table into excel file it is working fine for single table. What if I have multiple tables and want to create multiple worksheets from each table?

Comment: I highly recommend you download and use https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

Comment: PHPExcel is an incredibly powerful, flexible library for outputting  EXCEL spreadsheets. I don't think it is appropriate in this case and it does not address the OP's question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If each table has a unique `id`, you simply substitute that `id` into the first line. For example:

```
<table name="mytable" id="mytable">...</table>
<table name="urtable" id="urtable">...</table>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var t1 = document.getElementById('mytable');
var xl1 = t1.outerHTML;
window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(xl1));
var t2 = document.getElementById('urtable');
var xl2 = t2.outerHTML;
window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(xl2));
```

Comment: I tried this but it is creating multiple excel files I want them in multiple worksheet but in same workbook, in same excel file.

Comment: That's going to be a MUCH more involved process.. requiring the actual creation of an EXCEL workbook using the PHPExcel library that Len mentioned above.

Comment: I tried searching on http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/ but unfortunately got nothing will you please give me one small example for the same?

Comment: Try reading the documentation. PHPExcel is an OOP PHP library that you use to build real EXCEL files.

Comment: Thnak you very much @DevlshOne :) :)